# Built in Text To Speech in Android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Are there any built in Text To Speech Libraries in Android? and if not do you know any external libraries to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [Android TTS API](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html).

Here's an example of using it:

```
t1=new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if(status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                t1.setLanguage(Locale.UK);
            }
        }
    });

t1.speak("This will be spoken.", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
```

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/09/introduction-to-text-to-speech-in.html